# Unmarshalling XML to an Iterable<Long> using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have some very simple XML that I wish to unmarshall.  I'm only interested in the values for one of the elements which repeats.  Here's some sample XML:

```
<Document>
  <HeaderGuff>Whatever</HeaderGuff>
  <Foos>
    <FooId>1</FooId>
    <FooId>2</FooId>
  </Foos>
</Document>
```

I would like to use JAXB to allow me to iterate of the `FooId`'s as a `Long`.

The usual examples require creating a data class with `setFooId` and `getFooId` methods.  Is there a way to unmarshall directly to `Long` such that I can do this:

```
for ( Long fooId : <something JAXB> )
```

I do not want to load all the identifiers into memory at once as there are potentially many of them, and they are only needed one at a time for individual processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are only interested in one of the elements and don't want to bring all the data into memory at once I would use a StAX parser (included in the JDK/JRE since Java SE 6) instead of JAXB for this use case.

You would then advance your `XMLStreamReader` to the `FooId` element, process it and then advance it to the next element.

```
import javax.xml.stream.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        StreamSource source = new StreamSource("input.xml");
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(source);

        while(xsr.hasNext()) {
            if(xsr.isStartElement() && "FooId".equals(xsr.getLocalName())) {
                long value = Long.valueOf(xsr.getElementText());
                System.out.println(value);
            }
            xsr.next();
        }

        xsr.close();
    }

}
```